# What's the difference between Visual Studio 2008 Standard and Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comparison, t4

What does Pro have that's not in Standard (or vice-versa)?

I need Visual Studio for personal use but I can't use the Express editions because I need T4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a [nice list](http://deepdark.net/PermaLink,guid,9100f681-876b-4221-8ea9-eb7dc972be8d.aspx):

> Debugging Tools:
>
> - Attach to Remote Process
> - SQL-CLR Debugging
> - XSLT Debugger
> - T-SQL Debugging
>
> Data Tools:
>
> - Database Projects
> - SQL Server Projects
> - Server Explorer
>
> Reporting:
>
> - Crystal Reports Application & Crystal Reports for Visual Studio
>
> Office development:
>
> - VSTO for Office 2003 and Office 2007
> - Sharepoint 2007 State Machine workflow template
>
> Smart Device Development:
>
> - Device Emulator
> - Project Templates
> - Debugging Tools

Moocha and Filip Ekberg provided a really good reference to the [feature matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx).

---

From the comments:

- ctacke: Smart device development is better supported under Pro (Search for "Smart Device Development" on the [feature matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx))

Comment: For Smart Devices I'd also add Compilers and SDKs.  You can't even compile them from the command line without VS '08 Pro.

Comment: T4 is http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Download Center, "Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison Guide"
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en

Comment: it's the only link that is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Much as I hate to steer you away from giving us money, you'll find that T4 is indeed available in Express editions.

However, it's 'Add new item' templates are missing so it's not very obvious.
If you create a text file and then rename it to have a .tt extension then it should magically start working.